# Laravel query with primary key doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a users table with ID column as primary key.
I have this function in a Controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
         $items=user::all()->where('ID',$id);
        foreach ($items as $item) 
             echo $item->Name;
    }
```

This function doesn't echo anything. If I change from $id to $name like this:     `$items=user::all()->where('Name',$name);` it returns what should return.
ID is primary key in the table, it's not a fillable field in the Model. If i put ID in the fillable array it doesn't work either. It doesn't work even if I hardcode the id like this `$items=user::all()->where('ID','22');`

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all()` will run the query and return a collection of models, instead you should add the `where` call first and then use `get()` (or `first()`)

```
$items = User::where('ID', $id)->get();
```

For more information, please read the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)

Comment: Without seeing code I can say nothing about those other queries. Just keep in mind that `all()` will fetch a collection with all models from that table.